# How to do phone number authentication by sending and verifying otp in react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**I have searched Google, YouTube, Stackoverflow but I was not able to find a proper understandable tutorial to integrate phone number verification in react native app....If you know then please help me out.**

*I'm a beginner in react native*

Answer (score -1):

If you use firebase just follow this tuto: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth